# A la hora de hacer una notificación me da el error "java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities befor onCreate()"

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy tratando de mostrar una notificación mediante una alarma a una hora determinada, mi intención en recoger la alarma en la activity y gestionar la notificación en una clase independiente, el código es el siguiente:

```
public class Alarma extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


        noti noti=new noti();
        noti.notificaciones();


    }

    public class noti extends Activity{
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

        public void notificaciones(){

            int notifId=1;
            NotificationCompat.Builder constructorNotif = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
            constructorNotif.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_action_info_outline);
            constructorNotif.setContentTitle("Mi notificación");
            constructorNotif.setContentText("Has recibido una notificación!!");

            NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle =
                    new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
            String[] eventos = new String[5];
            inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle("Notificación expandible:");
            eventos[0]="Esto es la primera línea";
            eventos[1]="Esto es la segunda línea";
            eventos[2]="Esto es la tercera línea";
            eventos[3]="Esto es la cuarta línea";
            eventos[4]="Esto es la quita línea";
            for (int i=0; i < eventos.length; i++) {

                inboxStyle.addLine(eventos[i]);
            }
            constructorNotif.setWhen(0);
            constructorNotif.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);

            constructorNotif.setStyle(inboxStyle);



            NotificationManager notificador =
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            notificador.notify(notifId, constructorNotif.build());

        }

    }
}
```

El error seria este:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.ilm.democontentprovider, PID: 16325
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.example.ilm.avisador.Alarma: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
```

He tratado de llamar al metodo onCreate, pero no he conseguido nada, aun estoy muy perdido con android.

¿Existe una solución sencilla o tengo que replantearme la forma de hacerlo?

Añado la clase desde la que recojo la hora de la alarma:

```
public class Contactos extends Activity implements ListView.OnItemClickListener,ListView.OnItemLongClickListener,DialogoHora.OnHoraSeleccionada{

ListView l;
SQLiteDatabase db;
@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    return true;
}
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
    Contacto elegido = (Contacto) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, contacto.class);
    intent.putExtra("nombre",elegido.mName);
    intent.putExtra("id",elegido.id);
    startActivity(intent);

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contactos);
    l=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstContactos);
    l.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
    l.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    db=openOrCreateDatabase("MisCumples", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    ArrayList<Contacto> lista_contactos=new ArrayList<Contacto>();
    Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM miscumples order by nombre", null);
    if(c.getCount()==0){
        Contacto contacto=new Contacto();
        lista_contactos.add(contacto);}
        else{
            while(c.moveToNext()){
                Bitmap photo = null;
                String id = null;
            id = c.getString(0);
                Contacto contacto=new Contacto();
                contacto.id=c.getString(0);
                contacto.mName=c.getString(5);
                contacto.telefono=c.getString(3);
                if(c.getString(1).equals("0")){
                contacto.notificacion="Aviso: solo notificación";}else{
                    contacto.notificacion="Aviso: notificación y sms";
                }

    /*
    Usar el método de clase openContactPhotoInputStream()
     */
        try {
            InputStream input =
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(
                            getContentResolver(),
                            ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                                    ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                                    Long.parseLong(id))
                    );
            if (input != null) {
            /*
            Dar formato tipo Bitmap a los bytes del BLOB
            correspondiente a la foto
             */
                photo = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                input.close();
                Toast.makeText(this,"Se han encontrado en"+id+" una foto",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                contacto.mPhoto=photo;
            }

        } catch (IOException iox) { /* Manejo de errores */ }
                lista_contactos.add(contacto);
    }}
    c.close();

    ListView l=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstContactos);
    l.setAdapter(new Lista_adaptador(this, R.layout.fila_lista, lista_contactos){
        @Override
        public void onEntrada(Object entrada, View view) {
            TextView texto_superior_entrada = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_superior);
            texto_superior_entrada.setText(((Contacto) entrada).mName);

            TextView texto_inferior_entrada = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_inferior);
            texto_inferior_entrada.setText(((Contacto) entrada).notificacion);

            TextView texto_inferior_entrada2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_inferior2);
            texto_inferior_entrada2.setText(((Contacto) entrada).telefono);


            ImageView imagen_entrada = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView_imagen);
            imagen_entrada.setImageBitmap(((Contacto) entrada).mPhoto);
        }
    });
}
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.configura) {
        DialogoHora d=new DialogoHora();
        d.show(getFragmentManager(),"Mi diálogo Hora");
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onResultadoHora(GregorianCalendar hora) {
    Toast.makeText(this,hora.get(Calendar.HOUR)+":"+hora.get(Calendar.MINUTE),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    SetAlarma(hora.get(Calendar.HOUR),hora.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
}
public void SetAlarma(int hora,int minutos) {
    AlarmManager alarmMgr;
    PendingIntent alarmIntent;
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hora);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutos);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Alarma.class);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
}

public class Contacto {
    String mName;
    String telefono;
    String id;
    String notificacion;
    Bitmap mPhoto;

}
```

}

Comment: Definitivamente tu clase es incorrecto **No puedes extender de BroadcastReceiver  y dentro de esta clase definida que extienda de Activity!**, agregaría una respuesta pero en realidad tal vez no tengas definida una Activity, aporta más detalles. Por cierto aprovecha y ve el [tour] ;)

Comment: El caso es que necesito mostrar una notificación a una hora determinada, estoy haciendo una tarea de un curso y en los ejemplos del curso me muestra cómo crear las alarmas y como crear las notificaciones, pero no me muestra cómo combinar ambas, y todos mis intentos han sido inútiles. No sé qué más detalles de la aplicación podría dar, ya que hasta el punto de la alarma me funciona, por ejemplo si dentro del método onReceive cambio mi código por un toast me lo muestra sin problema, y me da la impresión que otros detalles de la aplicación solo complicarían la cuestión.

Comment: Que te parece si agregas las clases que estas usando?

Comment: Voy a añadir la clase desde la que recojo la hora de la alarma, a ver si ayuda en algo, aunque contiene bastante codigo que posiblemente no aporte nada.

Comment: Desde la clase contactos recojo la alarma, y quiero que a la hora que selecione el usuario se le muestre la notificacion.

Answer (score 0):

Ponogo una "solución" a mi problema:

Clase Alarma

```
public class Alarma extends BroadcastReceiver {
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    Intent intentone = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), noti.class);
    intentone.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intentone);

}

}
```

Clase noti:

```
public class noti extends Activity {
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    notificaciones();
}

public void notificaciones(){

    int notifId=1;
    NotificationCompat.Builder constructorNotif = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    constructorNotif.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_action_info_outline);
    constructorNotif.setContentTitle("Mi notificación");
    constructorNotif.setContentText("Has recibido una notificación!!");

    NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle =
            new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
    String[] eventos = new String[5];
    inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle("Notificación expandible:");
    eventos[0]="Esto es la primera línea";
    eventos[1]="Esto es la segunda línea";
    eventos[2]="Esto es la tercera línea";
    eventos[3]="Esto es la cuarta línea";
    eventos[4]="Esto es la quita línea";
    for (int i=0; i < eventos.length; i++) {

        inboxStyle.addLine(eventos[i]);
    }
    constructorNotif.setWhen(0);
    constructorNotif.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);

    constructorNotif.setStyle(inboxStyle);



    NotificationManager notificador =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificador.notify(notifId, constructorNotif.build());

}

}
```

Supongo que no es la mejor solución, pero me saca del apuro.